# BurpSuite API - Get Response from edited requests

Tags: security, burp

I have a problem with Burpsuite API that I can't find a proper function to print out the response for edited requests . I'm developing a new plugin for burpsuite with python . myscript is simply takes requests from proxy then it edit headers and send it again .

```py
from burp import IBurpExtender
from burp import IHttpListener


import re,urllib2

class BurpExtender(IBurpExtender, IHttpListener):
        
    def registerExtenderCallbacks(self, callbacks):
        self._callbacks = callbacks
        self._helpers = callbacks.getHelpers()
        callbacks.setExtensionName("Burp Plugin Python Demo")
        callbacks.registerHttpListener(self)
        return

    def processHttpMessage(self, toolFlag, messageIsRequest, currentRequest):
        # only process requests
        if messageIsRequest:
        
            requestInfo = self._helpers.analyzeRequest(currentRequest)
            #timestamp = datetime.now()        
            #print "Intercepting message at:", timestamp.isoformat()
            
            headers = requestInfo.getHeaders()
            #print url
            if(requestInfo.getMethod() == "GET"):
                print "GET"
                print requestInfo.getUrl()
                response = urllib2.urlopen(requestInfo.getUrl())
                print response
            elif(requestInfo.getMethod() == "POST"):
                print "POST"
                print requestInfo.getUrl()
            #for header in headers:
                #print header
            
            bodyBytes = currentRequest.getRequest()[requestInfo.getBodyOffset():]
            bodyStr = self._helpers.bytesToString(bodyBytes)
            bodyStr = re.sub(r'=(\w+)','=<xss>',bodyStr)
            newMsgBody = bodyStr
            newMessage = self._helpers.buildHttpMessage(headers, newMsgBody)
            print "Sending modified message:"
            print "----------------------------------------------"
            print self._helpers.bytesToString(newMessage)
            print "----------------------------------------------\n\n"
            currentRequest.setRequest(newMessage)
        return
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to print the response but you don't do anything in case `messageIsRequest` is false. When `messageIsRequest` is false it means that the `currentRequest` is a response and you can print out the response as you did for the request. I did it in Java like this:

```py
def processHttpMessage(self, toolFlag, messageIsRequest, httpRequestResponse):
    if messageIsRequest:
        # ...
    else
        HTTPMessage = httpRequestResponse.getResponse()
        print HTTPMessage
```

There is even a method that lets you bind request and response together when using a proxy. It can be found in `IInterceptedProxyMessage`:

```java
/**
 * This method retrieves a unique reference number for this
 * request/response.
 *
 * @return An identifier that is unique to a single request/response pair.
 * Extensions can use this to correlate details of requests and responses
 * and perform processing on the response message accordingly.
 */
int getMessageReference();
```

I don't think it is supported for `HTTPListeners`.

I am writing the extensions in Java and tried to translate to Python for this answer. I haven't tested this code and some bugs might be introduced due to translation.